# How can I place a folder in a specific location using javafx-ant with Maven?

Tags: ant, maven-3, javafx-8

I have upgraded my build from plain ANT to Maven to manage dependencies.  One of my Third Party Jars needs a supporting file placed in a specific location.

I have managed to create a simple pom.xml to compile the application and generate the EXE installer.  However I am unable to place this file in the specific folder location.

When the application is build & deployed it should be placed in this location:

```
${project.build.directory}/deploy/bundles/MyApplication/app/{custom-folder}/*.properties
```

This want it would be correctly bundled in the installer - however I am unable to find a way to specify a specific location for a specific file.

Following this pattern (only showing the relative pieces of the POM):

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<phase>package</phase>
<configuration>
<target>

<taskdef name="jfxdeploy" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
    <jfxdeploy outdir="${project.build.directory}/deploy" outfile="${build.finalName}" nativeBundles="all">
    <resources>                         
        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/dependency" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/properties" includes="*.properties" />
   </resources>
....
```

This places the *.properties file in the location

```
${project.build.directory}/deploy/bundles/MyApplication/app
```

Is there a way to place this in a sub folder at this location?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue.  I needed to change the mapping in the fileset as follows:

```
<fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="properties/*.properties"/>
```

This placed it where it needed to be.